# How to access a local website from another devices connected to the same WIFI network?

Tags: apache, localhost

I run Apache on my laptop and develop a website. The local domain is bee.off. I want to check site's design from mobile phone. I can only access localhost, but not other local domains. So what do I do?

My config for bee.off is below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName bee.off
 DirectoryIndex index.php
 DocumentRoot /home/ovin-off/www/bee.off
 <Directory /home/ovin-off/www/bee.off>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     Require all granted
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
     AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/bee.off-error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/bee.off-access.log combined
```

Comment: Hmm.. enter the local WLAN ip of your laptop in the mobile's browser? (and make sure the firewall on the laptop is off or allows the connection and check if apache is listening on 0.0.0.0 instead of  127.0.0.1)

Comment: @Harry, by entering the local WLAN IP of my laptop I get onto localhost (default apache dir). How to check if apache is listening on 0.0.0.0 and why is this important?

Comment: Sounds like either you get to a different webserver or you just enter the wrong url. Enter the same url that you use locally in the mobile browser, just exchanging localhost by the wlan ip. Check in the httpd.conf file or by using the commandline "netstat -ano|findstr LISTEN" - or change LISTEN to your language or remove the whole "|findstr part. This is important because when apache only listens on 127.0.0.1, you can only reach it on localhost.

Comment: @Harry I added my config to the question. When I type bee.off in my phone's browser, nothing happens, it doesn't know about such an address. I'm sure I get to the same web server, because I added my file to localhost and can get access to it by typing in phone: my_laptop_ip/file.php

Comment: Sounds like you just have a name resolution problem. the domain name "bee.off" doesnt sound like an A-record on internet DNS servers, so how do you plan to make your iphone resolve the DNS "bee.off"? does your private WLAN router allow you to add custom DNS entries? And why does it matter for you how your internal lan devices access the stuff - isnt it only of interest how users from the internet reach it?

Comment: For the record, I have One Plus, not Iphone. It matters, because I want to test my platform on mobile device before uploading to the server.

Comment: so, were you able to solve your DNS problem? If you just want to test on your mobile, the DNS actually would not matter, just access the stuff using IP.

Comment: I found that it is called virtual hosts in apache. The default is localhost and I can I access it, but can't access others.

Comment: As you can reach your apache using IP, settings of your apache.conf are not really of matter for your problem. You need to look out for a DNS server or any other way to make your mobile to resolve the hostname "bee.off". Typical methods for it is to modify hosts file (need root access), DNS, NetBIOS or WINS